# Can't change session service name in torii

Tags: session, ember.js, firebase, ember-simple-auth

I'm using `ember-simple-auth` and `emberfire` to authenticate users on my app. One thing I don't like about the defaults is that there is both a "session" service and a "session" object on the service. So, I opened `config/environment.js` and changed:

```
var Env = {
  torii: {
    sessionServiceName: 'session',
    providers: {
      'firebase-simple-auth': {}
    }
   }
 ...
```

to

```
var Env = {
  torii: {
    sessionServiceName: 'auth',
    providers: {
      'firebase-simple-auth': {}
    }
   }
 ...
```

But, the newly named "auth" service doesn't have the "invalidate" and "authenticate" methods. Those are still on the "session" service (which I'm surprised is still around).

How do I move the entire "session" service over to an "auth" service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are configuring torii, not ESA. When you use the 2 in combination though you're not actually using torii's session at all. Ember Simple Auth's session service cannot be renamed but that's also not necessary anyway as you explicitly inject it anyway and can specify a custom name when doing so.